# Using each in PHP like jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm used to using jQuery's `each` to go through an array and now I need to do the same in PHP, but I'm not quite sure how. PHP's `each` doesn't work quite the same way.

Given the following array, I know in jquery I could do something like the following to get the `id` value from each of the `entry` fields:

```
$.each(obj.entry, function(i, data) {
console.log(data.id);
});
```

The question I have is how to do this same thing in PHP. I tried:

```
//code to generate `$json` up here
echo $json; //returns array shown below
$newarray =json_decode($json, true);
$broke = each($newarray);
```

What do I need to do differently to get all the `id` from all the entries? Assume there will be around 100 or so.

Example JSON object below:

```
{
  "id": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppodcasts/limit=2/explicit=true/xml",
  "title": "iTunes Store: Top Podcasts",
  "updated": "2016-02-11T07:26:05-07:00",
  "link": [{
    "@attributes": {
      "rel": "alternate",
      "type": "text/html",
      "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewTop?cc=us&id=38&popId=3"
    }
  }, {
    "@attributes": {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppodcasts/limit=2/explicit=true/xml"
    }
  }],
  "icon": "http://itunes.apple.com/favicon.ico",
  "author": {
    "name": "iTunes Store",
    "uri": "http://www.apple.com/itunes/"
  },
  "rights": "Copyright 2008 Apple Inc.",
  "entry": [{
    "updated": "2016-02-11T07:26:05-07:00",
    "id": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/serial/id917918570?mt=2&uo=2",
    "title": "Serial - This American Life",
    "summary": "Serial is a podcast from the creators of This American Life, hosted by Sarah Koenig. Serial unfolds one story - a true story - over the course of a whole season. The show follows the plot and characters wherever they lead, through many surprising twists and turns. Sarah won't know what happens at the end of the story until she gets there, not long before you get there with her. Each week she'll bring you the latest chapter, so it's important to listen in, starting with Episode 1. New episodes are released on Thursday mornings.",
    "link": {
      "@attributes": {
        "rel": "alternate",
        "type": "text/html",
        "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/serial/id917918570?mt=2&uo=2"
      }
    },
    "category": {
      "@attributes": {
        "term": "News & Politics",
        "scheme": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-news-politics/id1311?mt=2&uo=2",
        "label": "News & Politics"
      }
    },
    "rights": "© Copyright 2016 Serial Podcast",
    "content": "<table border=\"0\" width=\"100%\">\n    <tr>\n        <td>\n            <table border=\"0\" width=\"100%\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">\n                <tr valign=\"top\" align=\"left\">\n                    \n                        <td align=\"center\" width=\"166\" valign=\"top\">\n                            <a href=\"https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/serial/id917918570?mt=2&uo=2\"><img border=\"0\" alt=\"This American Life - Serial  artwork\" src=\"http://is2.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts69/v4/90/ef/70/90ef704d-a2d6-ca6f-6972-1b62f8eadb01/mza_7676577196916555630.png/170x170bb-85.jpg\" /></a>\n                        </td>\n                        <td width=\"10\"><img alt=\"\" width=\"10\" height=\"1\" src=\"https://s.mzstatic.com/images/spacer.gif\" /></td>\n                    \t<td width=\"95%\">\n                    \n                    \n                        <b><a href=\"https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/serial/id917918570?mt=2&uo=2\">Serial</a></b><br/>\n                        \n                        \n                        \n                        \n\n                        <a href=\"https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/wbez/id364380278?mt=2&amp;uo=2\">This American Life</a>\n\n                       <font size=\"2\" face=\"Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \t<br/>\n                            <b>Genre:</b> <a href=\"https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-news-politics/id1311?mt=2&uo=2\">News & Politics</a>\n                        \n\t\t\t\t\t\t \t<br/>\n                            <b>Release Date:</b> February 6, 2016\n                        \n                        </font>\n                    </td>\n                </tr>\n            </table>\n        </td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n        <td>\n            \n                <font size=\"2\" face=\"Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular\"><br/>Serial is a podcast from the creators of This American Life, hosted by Sarah Koenig. Serial unfolds one story - a true story - over the course of a whole season. The show follows the plot and characters wherever they lead, through many surprising twists and turns. Sarah won&#39;t know what happens at the end of the story until she gets there, not long before you get there with her. Each week she&#39;ll bring you the latest chapter, so it&#39;s important to listen in, starting with Episode 1. New episodes are released on Thursday mornings.</font><br/>\n            \n            \n            \n                <font size=\"2\" face=\"Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular\"> &#169; © Copyright 2016 Serial Podcast</font>\n\t        \n        </td>\n    </tr>\n</table>\n"
  }, {
    "updated": "2016-02-11T07:26:05-07:00",
    "id": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/real-crime-profile/id1081244497?mt=2&uo=2",
    "title": "Real Crime Profile - Real Crime Profile",
    "summary": "Podcast talking about criminal cases and personality profiling.",
    "link": {
      "@attributes": {
        "rel": "alternate",
        "type": "text/html",
        "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/real-crime-profile/id1081244497?mt=2&uo=2"
      }
    },
    "category": {
      "@attributes": {
        "term": "History",
        "scheme": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-history/id1462?mt=2&uo=2",
        "label": "History"
      }
    },
    "rights": "© All rights reserved",
    "content": "<table border=\"0\" width=\"100%\">\n    <tr>\n        <td>\n            <table border=\"0\" width=\"100%\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">\n                <tr valign=\"top\" align=\"left\">\n                    \n                        <td align=\"center\" width=\"166\" valign=\"top\">\n                            <a href=\"https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/real-crime-profile/id1081244497?mt=2&uo=2\"><img border=\"0\" alt=\"Real Crime Profile - Real Crime Profile  artwork\" src=\"http://is5.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts69/v4/ff/fa/95/fffa95d2-5156-2f85-8e2e-1b2bc3a82236/mza_1683998348979602855.jpg/170x170bb-85.jpg\" /></a>\n                        </td>\n                        <td width=\"10\"><img alt=\"\" width=\"10\" height=\"1\" src=\"https://s.mzstatic.com/images/spacer.gif\" /></td>\n                    \t<td width=\"95%\">\n                    \n                    \n                        <b><a href=\"https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/real-crime-profile/id1081244497?mt=2&uo=2\">Real Crime Profile</a></b><br/>\n                        \n                        \n                        \n                        \n\n                        Real Crime Profile\n\n                       <font size=\"2\" face=\"Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \t<br/>\n                            <b>Genre:</b> <a href=\"https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-history/id1462?mt=2&uo=2\">History</a>\n                        \n\t\t\t\t\t\t \t<br/>\n                            <b>Release Date:</b> February 2, 2016\n                        \n                        </font>\n                    </td>\n                </tr>\n            </table>\n        </td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n        <td>\n            \n                <font size=\"2\" face=\"Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular\"><br/>Podcast talking about criminal cases and personality profiling.</font><br/>\n            \n            \n            \n                <font size=\"2\" face=\"Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular\"> &#169; © All rights reserved</font>\n\t        \n        </td>\n    </tr>\n</table>\n"
  }]
}
```

Comment: why each? why not `foreach`?

Comment: @MarcB I get now that it's `foreach`, but I'm not quite sure how to apply in my situation where I have to iterate through `entry` within my object. All of the answers seem to iterate through `id` (which is what I need), but one level too high in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your JSON String represents an object I would leave it as an object i.e. loose the `,true` in the `json_decode()`

```
$jObj = json_decode($json);

foreach( $jObj->entry as $entry ) {
    echo $entry->id . PHP_EOL;
    echo $entry->title . PHP_EOL;
    echo $entry->updated . PHP_EOL;
}
```

To make a new object out of what you take from the original data you coudl do something like this

```
$jObj = json_decode($json);

$new = new stdClass();  // create a new object

foreach( $jObj->entry as $entry ) {
    $t = new stdClass();

    $t->id      = $entry->id;
    $t->title   = $entry->title;
    $t->updated = $entry->updated;

    $new->entries[] = $t;   // create an array of objects
}


$newJsonString = json_encode($new);
```

Comment: This is close, but the problem is that it doesn't go "down" to the right level. I need to get id, title, and updated from within `entry`. Your code gets the values from the top level.

Comment: Ah, missed that, just a minute

Comment: Thanks...and I also need to do `foreach` to get all of the values I need for the multiple objects under `entry`

Comment: Tried the new code, but this didn't return anything.

Comment: Sorry SPelling erorrr, refresh page

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I guess I need to dig into what `PHP_EOL` is.

Comment: Perfect...the new addition to the code gives me everything I need. Is there a simple way to wrap this all up into a new JSON object?

Comment: Is that somewhere near what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks...pretty close, I think. Throwing an error though :"Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rss/untitled.php on line 67" This is referring to one of these two lines: `$newJsonString = json_encode($new);
echo($new);`

Comment: Use `print_r($new);` to see what the new object looks like, `print_r()` works on objects and arrays. `echo` only works on scalar variables

Comment: This gives all the right data, but not in JSON format (or least doesn't quite look like JSON)

Comment: Then `echo $newJsonString;` that is the new JSON data that you would transport about to javascript or whereever

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach($newarray as $key => $value) {
    echo $key; // 0, 1, 2, etc
    echo $value['id'] ; // echos ID
}
```

Comment: This returns nothing with my data. Does the `$newarray` need to be sent through `json_decode` first or something?

Comment: @jonmrich in your question, you show $newarray being decoded with json.  so, yes.  `$newarray =json_decode($json, true);`

Comment: Sorry...my mistake...confused myself with my example code. Here's what is returned with your code: "idhtitleiupdated2linkiconhauthorrightsCentry" I think the issue is that it isn't going down to the right level. I need to iterate and get the `id` values from `entry` in my object. I think your code doesn't go down into `entry`.

Comment: @jonmrich - I see.  So the other way would be to put another foreach loop inside .  `foreach($value as $v) { echo $v['id'] }`  I'm glad you were able to solve it!

Answer (score 1):

PHP has [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for this kind of operation

```
foreach($data as $key=> $value){
   echo $value['id'];// or whatever you need
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get this conceptually, but this isn't quite working. I'm not getting down into the `entry` part of the object, so this `echo`s nothing.

Comment: How about print_r($value['entry'])

Comment: Or you can print $value array and access other elemeng like above?

Comment: `print_r($value['entry']) ` didn't give me anything back.

Comment: Can you print $newArray?

Answer (score 0):

You can use php `foreach` loop:

```
   foreach($newarray as $key => $value) {
        // do smthg here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) and [foreach](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php) statements.

```
$row = json_decode($jsonString);
foreach($row as $key => $value) {
 echo $key, '=>', $value;
 // for you in $value will be key id $value['id']
}
```

Comment: This gave me something, but not what I needed. `id=>https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppodcasts/limit=2/explicit=true/xmltitle=>iTunes Store: Top Podcastsupdated=>2016-02-11T07:26:05-07:00link=>Arrayicon=>http://itunes.apple.com/favicon.icoauthor=>` I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "// for you in $value will be key id $value['id']"